# Project reference to another project with different target platform in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure, azure-functions

I am developing Azure Function in visual studio, it running well locally. When I try to publish to AZ, it gives me failed error: Please change project B target platform to x64 via build configuration manager.

But I already did so, otherwise it can not running, even locally. However, I did not change the target platform to x64 in the dialog after I right click the project B's properties.

Problem is after I make the change there, it did not working even locally. Project A with target platform AnyCPU which reference to peoject B gives me another error: Project A: Could not load file or assembly, Project B.

Any idea on how this whole thing should work both locally and on Azure. Am I in the wrong place at beginning?

They all in same solution, the executing project call Porject A, and project A call project B

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting both projects to use AnyCPU ?

Comment: Change both target platforms for both A and B projects to x64. Since that is the target of AZ.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Yes, I tried that. But it gives me error please change project B's target platform to x64. I guess due to other reasons, Project B have to be on x64. I am not sure, can I have projects with different target platform in one solution?(And in my case, one also reference to another) Thanks

Comment: @Strom Since the executing project calling Project A, if I change A to x64 also, it gives error: could not load file or assembly Project A. Thanks

Comment: Lets me ask you, is the local or Azure server the application is running on both x86 and x64? No. That should answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that `Platform target` in Property pages (aka right click on Project, `Properties> Build`) controls the platform indeed. Leave it as `Any CPU` and change `Configuration manager` to x64, projects are built as x86, i.e. the preference of `Any CPU`. I also find in a brand new project, modify `Configuration manager` to x64, `Platform target` is changed to x64 automatically and projects are built into x64 bits.

So I guess *running well locally* happened because your projects actually targeted at x86 before. After `Platform target` changed, x64 doesn't work well due to the inconsistency of projects platform.

Based on this, I would suggest as @Jeremy said, make sure all project Platforms are set to `Any CPU`, we could delete x64 platform settings directly for a clean configuration.

---

If you choose to set all project platform to x64, follow steps below.

VS consumes x86 runtime by default, to debug x64 functions we have to download x64 cli(containing runtime) and configure manually.

1. Visit [cli release note](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/releases) to download latest x64 bits(1.x for v1 .NET Framework Functions, 2.x for v2 .NET Core Functions). For example, for v2 functions on OS Windows, we could choose `Azure.Functions.Cli.min.win-x64.2.4.317`.
2. Right click on your project->Properties, do debug configuration below.

   ```
   Launch: Executable
   Executable: [x64CliPath]\func.exe
   Application Arguments: host start
   ```

   [image]
3. Before publish, don't forget to modify Platform to 64-bit on Application settings in Azure portal.

Comment: Yes, however, due to other reasons, project B has to be remain x64, otherwise errors. Wondering if I could have two project with different target platform in one solution, especially one is reference to another. Thanks

Comment: @tuoba Sorry for the late, I am afraid it's not possible to reference project with different target platform, is it acceptable to set all projects to x64?

Comment: thanks for your help. Problem here is, if I set all the project to x64, then I can not run it even locally. Error: Could not load file or assembly. Need find tricky way around.

Comment: @tuoba Did you follow my updated solution to download x64 function runtime?

Comment: yes, and The program '[5068] func.exe' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a). thanks

Comment: @tuoba Can you confirm the cli fits your function version? e.g for v1 functions we need to download [1.0.18](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/releases/tag/1.0.18) cli `Azure.Functions.Cli.x64.zip`. Also if you did work with v1 functions, I once see people came across this `1073741510` code due to the version conflict of `Newtonsoft.Json`, v1 needs exact v9.0.1.